# Question concerning tensors

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, tensors

As some of you may have seen from my previous question(s), I am working through Spivak's Calc on Manifolds and this happens to be the first time I've been introduced to tensors formally, though I have come into contact with specific instances of them in certain classes in school (fluid mechanics, solid mechanics, electromagnetism). I'm asking if anyone has a specific technique for understanding these objects. The following is my (imprecise) interpretation, please correct me if I'm wrong to think this way and as usual, any insight is greatly appreciated.

So a 0 order tensor is a scalar, a tensor of order 1 is a vector. My understanding of a 2nd order tensor is that, since each element requires two indices to specify, a 2nd order tensor may be represented as a matrix, when "placed" in any coordinate system of course. Now, if we continue this pattern, it seems to me that in order to represent a 3rd order tensor, one must actually construct a geometric "object" somewhat analogous to a cube, with each face being a matrix. Is this interpretation correct?

As a side note, if the above is correct, it does seem that such objects would inevitably have been discovered at some point. Why confine the quantitative relationships between mathematical objects to a point, line or plane? It seems this is a generalization which naturally should arise.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a lot, due to boredom and the general hope that some of it is helpful. Much will probably be familiar to you.

First: In order to work with tensors or to do calculus on manifolds at all, it's very important to start making the distinction between *vectors* and *covectors* (or "dual vectors" or whatever). Briefly, if $V$ is a (finite dimensional, real) vector space, there's an associated (real) vector space $V^*$ which is the set of linear maps $V \to \mathbb{R}$. $V^*$ is called the *dual* to $V$, and its elements are called *covectors* or *dual vectors*.

When $V = \mathbb{R}^n$ as in college linear algebra courses, we often make the identification of $V$ with column vectors, and $V^*$ with row vectors. We have an easy way of taking a column vector and making a row vector or vice versa (taking the transpose), so often we don't distinguish between the two and just call everything a "vector". But *on a manifold*, there are many different possible choices of coordinates making the tangent spaces look like $\mathbb{R}^n$ in different ways, which means that there's no "natural" way to take a "transpose" of a tangent vector. This means that it's important to think of tangent vectors and tangent covectors as very different things; which means back in linear algebra world, we need to differentiate between $V$ and $V^*$.

Said another way, there's two different kinds of "one-tensors" on a vector space $V$: what's called a $(0,1)$-tensor, which is an ordinary vector, an element of $V$, and what's called a $(1,0)$-tensor, which is a *covector*, an element of $V^*$. It's the right intuition to think of $(0,1)$-tensors as column vectors and $(1,0)$-tensors as row vectors, but you should remember that "transpose" isn't meaningful in this generality (and won't be when you start talking about tangent spaces to smooth manifolds).

So in general it's confusing to talk about "$n$-tensors"; instead the correct notion is that of a $(k,l)$-tensor, which is a multilinear map
$$
   T : V \times \cdots \times V \times V^* \times \cdots \times V^* \to \mathbb{R},
$$
where there are $k$ copies of $V$ and $l$ copies of $V^*$.

A matrix $A$ is a $(1,1)$-tensor, because it eats a row vector (an element of $V^*$) and a column vector (an element of $V$) and produces a number. Differential geometers will write the element of a matrix $A$ in the $i$-th row and $j$-th column as $A^j_i$; the idea of writing the $i$ as a subscript, and the $j$ as a superscript, is to explicitly indicate that the matrix is a $(1,1)$-tensor.

A good example of a $(2,0)$-tensor on a vector space $V$ is an inner product, since an inner product is suppose to eat two *vectors* and tell you something about the angle between them and their lengths and so forth. It's misleading to picture an inner product as a matrix -- you want to say that the inner product given by the matrix $A$ is the map taking the vectors $u, v$ to $u^T A v$, but without coordinates we can't make sense of $u^T$, which means that we won't be able to make sense of $u^T$ in a coherent way when we're on the tangent space to a manifold (where there are many choices of coordinates).

So if you wanted to be able to take tangent vectors (at the same point) to your manifold $M$ and do inner-product things to them like measure the angle between them, you'd want for each tangent space $T_pM$ a $(2, 0)$-tensor on that space -- known as a $(2,0)$-tensor *field* on $M$ -- with some nice properties that make it an inner product and "vary smoothly". A $(1,1)$-tensor field just wouldn't do the job! (But I digress... I don't want to be discussing tensor fields.)

**This is all a preamble to saying that I think the intuition "a $3$-tensor is like a cube of numbers" is not a particularly helpful way to think about things,** because (1) you can't write a cube of numbers down on paper very easily and (2) **it obscures that there's a fundamental difference between "row-like" things and "column-like" things,** and that each of the "axes" of this "cube of numbers" should really be marked "row-like" or "column-like" to determine whether it acts on column vectors or row vectors. (There really are only these *two* kinds of vectors we're considering in differential geometry -- no weird "depth vectors" or whatever.)

So *if* you want to think about tensors in coordinates, with numbers, like you do when you call a $(1,1)$-tensor a matrix, I think the best you can do is to think of a $(k,l)$ tensor $T$ as a list of numbers
$$
   T^{j_1, \dots, j_k}_{i_1, \dots, i_l}
$$
where the $i$'s and $j$'s each run from $1$ to $n$ (where $n = \dim V$). (Just like with writing down the matrix of a linear transformation, actually writing a tensor as such a list of numbers requires first choosing a basis for $V$.) The top indicies run across generalized "rows" and the bottom down generalized "columns", but I'm not sure this really means anything or is a useful way to think. I don't have a coherent system for writing such huge lists/arrays/whatever down on paper. Relatedly, it's also the case that I almost never do write such things down on paper.

How does this list of numbers become a linear transformation? It's just like matricies. Fixing a basis on $V$ (and hence also on $V^*$), we can write elements of $V$ as $(0,1)$-tensors, which are lists of numbers $v_i$, for $1 \leq i \leq n$, and elements of $V^*$ are $(1,0)$-tensors, which are lists of numbers $w^j$. So say we have a $(3,2)$-tensor $T^{j_1, j_2, j_3}_{i_1, i_2}$ and three vectors $u_i, v_i, w_i$ and two covectors $a^i, b^i$; then the tensor $T$ evaluated at $(u, v, w, a, b)$ is the number
$$
   \sum_{1 \leq j_i, j_2, j_3, i_1, i_2 \leq n} T^{j_1, j_2, j_3}_{i_1, i_2} u_{j_1} u_{j_2} u_{j_3} a^{i_1} b^{i_2} ,
$$
which is what it looks like -- a mess. Luckily, we don't have to think about tensors this way very often.

Comment: I think that last formula is a beautiful mess. Formulas are fun.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! This is very informative for me because, thus far in the book, the author makes no mention of say $(k,l)$ tensors, he only states the definition of a $k$-tensor, which apparently is misleading. This post is precisely what I was looking for, thank you so much!

Comment: I have never heard someone compare row vectors and column vectors in the context of explaining differential forms and vectors. Why isn't this connection to dual spaces mentioned in standard intro to linear algebra? It's like it gets lost. The linear algebra people don't talk about the tensors and the differential geometry people don't talk about row vs column vectors. Makes it hard to find information.

Answer (score 1):

I know of no algebra in which 3d arrays of numbers can be manipulated with the same ease as matrices.  Part of that has to do with how any linear map from one space to another space can be represented with a matrix.  You can chain such maps together sensibly (and really, only in one way up to the order of how you compose those operations together), whereas chaining general tensors together has considerably more freedom:  when you're chaining operations together, on which arguments do they act?  And so on.

Further, I would object to considering matrices to be "geometrical" in any such sense.  Yes, you can *write them down* as a 2d array, but that arrangement of entries in the matrix doesn't have anything to do with the actual geometry of the underlying manifold or vector space.