# Can rank 2 tensors with different components be the same tensor?

Tags: tensors, multilinear-algebra

I have very little experience and exposure to working with tensors. I know what a tensor is definitionally from a linear algebra course, and I know that rank 2 tensors transform in a particular way (this is the extent of my knowledge).

My question: Is there a way to determine if two tensors are the same even if their components are different?

This questions comes about because I am using mathematica to convert a 2-rank tensor from spherical coordinates to cartesian coordinates. I then converted the tensor back into spherical coordinates. The matrix I ended up with is different that the one I stated with. My guess is that this is happening because the rank 2 tensor transform multiplies one side by a matrix and the other by that matrix's transpose. Thus, performing this transformation and then performing the transform in the opposite way DOES NOT mean you're net multiplying the original tensor by identity matrices. So, perhaps you do not end up with what you started with.

Attached is a picture of my initial and end matrix (in spherical coordinates). All help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: Added code used in case that is helpful.

[image]

Comment: Damn that was a quick progression from the previous questions on hoff man and kunze

Comment: What is this tensor supposed to represent? A matrix?

Comment: Hm. I am not sure I have the understanding to clarify what you're asking for. I can give more context, though. This tensor represents a physics thing. It represents quadrupole moment. If charge is a scalar, dipole moment is a vector, then quadrupole moment is a two index matrix. Let me know if this helps. @EthakkaappamwithChai

Comment: I mean not all rank two tensor are matrices.. @Silly Goose. Being representable in array doesn't mean same as being a matrix( weird I know)

Comment: Ah. My guess is that it is a matrix. Because the definition of quadrupole moment includes that the quadrupole moment matrix is traceless and symmetric (which seem to be concepts to do with matricies). This guess may be utterly wrong.

Comment: You can actually define trace and symmetry for the actual indexed value of (2,0) or (0,2) tensor as well see the answer I linked by peekaboo

Comment: In most physic book I find quadrupole moment is written as lower index tensor of two indices. This means transformation rule is $Q_{i'j'} = Q_{ij} J_{i'}^i J_{j'}^j$ where $J_{i'}^i$ is the jacobian of old coordinate by new (i.e: the matrix which takes us from new basis back to old)

Comment: What happend in the end?

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai I was able to get my code to work :). It turns out that the first conversion (from spherical to cartesian) is correct. Since this is a project related thing, I am going to try and debug and understand why the conversion back to spherical seems different later. But your answer and comment (and Deane's answer) were helpful for helping me understand how this type of tensor transforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to distinguish between a linear transformation (which you call a matrix) and a $2$-tensor. From the definition of the quadrupole moment, it appears that it is a $2$-tensor.

Recall that, given a vector space $V$, a $2$-tensor is a function $\newcommand\R{\mathbb{R}}$
$$
T: V\times V \rightarrow \R
$$
that is bilinear. If you choose a basis $(b_1,b_2, b_3)$ of $V$, then the tensor is uniquely determined by its value for pairs of basis vectors,
$$
T_{ij} = T(b_i,b_j).
$$
If you remember this, then it is straightforward to figure out how the components change when you change to a new basis of $V$. But observe that the components of $T$ are indeed uniquely determined by $T$ itself and the basis $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$. So it's not possible for two tensors to be equal if their components are not.

Now observe that if you have a new basis $(e_1, e_2, e_3)$, then you can write the old basis in terms of a new basis, using a matrix,
\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix} b_1 & b_2 & b_3\end{bmatrix}
&=
\begin{bmatrix} e_1 & e_2 & e_3 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} M^1_1 & M^1_2 & M^1_3 \\ M^2_1 & M^2_2 & M^2_3 \\ M^3_1 & M^3_2 & M^3_3 \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
The components of the tensor with respect to the new basis are now easily computed using the bilinear property of $T$:
$$
T(e_i, e_j) = T(b_kM^k_i, b_lM^l_j) = M^k_iM^l_jT(b_k,b_l).
$$
If you call the components of the tensor with respect to the new basis $\widehat{T}_{ij}$, then the formula is
$$
\widehat{T}_{ij} = M^k_iM^l_jT_{kl}.
$$
Although it is easy to remember this formula, it is always hard for me to remember whether the components on the left are with respect to the old or new basis. So I just remember the abstract definitions and work out the formula from scratch each time I need it.

I think it is indeed a good idea to do this computation by hand first.

Answer (score 1):

If by rank-two, you mean a two index tensor then there are actually three possible rank two tensor a (1,1) , (0,2) and a (2,0) tensor. Each transform by very different rules. Fr more details have a look at [peek-a-boo's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4458984/could-the-linear-algebra-concepts-regarding-n-times-n-matrices-be-used-on-any) here.

Supposing that quadrupole tensor is a two lower index tensor, we have:

$$Q_{i'j'} = Q_{ij} J_{i'}^i J_{j'}^j$$

Or,

$$ Q_{B'} =J Q_{B} J^T$$

Comment: btw if you ues the correct transformation rule it must be that you should get the same component you started with if you convert and convert back with the right rule

Comment: I see. I am going to try and do the transform by hand and compare with what mathematica spits out.